# Realtime Detect Hardware Device

Tags: ios, ipad, web

I would like to be able to detect teh exact tablet being used e.g. differentiating between an iPad Air 2 or Samsung Tab 4, serving a different web page for each tablet device, with links to tablet cases for that particular hardware product.
I found some device detection via netbiscuits.com but want to go that level further to serve a different webpage for a particular hardware device.  I have already successfully been able to detect between, mobile, tablet and desktop via Responsive Web Design.
I would like to be able to detect teh exact tablet being used e.g. fiffereenating between an iPad Air 2 or Samsung Tab 4, serving a different web page with links to tabket cases for that particular product.

I found some device detection via netbiscuits.com but want to go that level further to serve a different webpage for a particular hardware device.  I have already successfully been able to detect between, mobile, tablet and desktop via Responsive Web Design.

Comment: You may want to change the tags as this is not an android, ios or ipad issue, but a web related issue.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself (with a lot of effort), the `User-Agent` string should do the job, no?